# Remove portion of string PHP

Tags: php, string, loops, rss, simplexml

I am working with some RSS data. I am trying to remove certain parts of the string.

The string is like this:

```
<description><![CDATA[<div style="float:right;margin:0 0 1ex 1ex"><a href="/link/123" rel="nofollow" title="Link: www.example.com/testing-information"><img src="http://www.example.com/a/100/1000.jpg?hash=a38232k" alt="More info here"/></a></div><p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>
```

I only want to display:

```
**THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP**
```

or

```
**<p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>**
```

I am using PHP and would like to store the value as a variable.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like part of XML, try using [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) on the full string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.strip-tags.php), if you want keep the p tag, add the second parameter `<p>`

```
    <?php
      //without p tag
      echo strip_tags('<description><![CDATA[<div style="float:right;margin:0 0 1ex 1ex"><a href="/link/123" rel="nofollow" title="Link: www.example.com/testing-information"><img src="http://www.example.com/a/100/1000.jpg?hash=a38232k" alt="More info here"/></a></div><p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>');
      echo "\n";
      //with p tag
      echo strip_tags('<description><![CDATA[<div style="float:right;margin:0 0 1ex 1ex"><a href="/link/123" rel="nofollow" title="Link: www.example.com/testing-information"><img src="http://www.example.com/a/100/1000.jpg?hash=a38232k" alt="More info here"/></a></div><p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>', '<p>');
```

and the output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP
<p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = '<description><![CDATA[<div style="float:right;margin:0 0 1ex 1ex"><a href="/link/123" rel="nofollow" title="Link: www.example.com/testing-information"><img src="http://www.example.com/a/100/1000.jpg?hash=a38232k" alt="More info here"/></a></div><p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>';
preg_match('~<p>(.*?)</p>~', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)** :

```
$text = '<description><![CDATA[<div style="float:right;margin:0 0 1ex 1ex"><a href="/link/123" rel="nofollow" title="Link: www.example.com/testing-information"><img src="http://www.example.com/a/100/1000.jpg?hash=a38232k" alt="More info here"/></a></div><p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

**[Working Demo](http://phpio.net/s/2diu)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for text information other than xhtml tags, you can do that by `strip_tags($text)` in php-example-

```
$text = '<description><![CDATA[<div style="float:right;margin:0 0 1ex 1ex"><a href="/link/123" rel="nofollow" title="Link: www.example.com/testing-information"><img src="http://www.example.com/a/100/1000.jpg?hash=a38232k" alt="More info here"/></a></div><p>THIS IS THE INFO I ACTUALLY WANT TO KEEP</p>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";
```